# Подключение Npgsql к Unity-проекту

Tags: c#, unity3d, npgsql

Никак не могу подключить Npgsql к Своему Unity-проекту. dll-файл я получил, скачав соответствующее расширение, но куда его пристроить - ума не приложу. В интернете не нашёл тольковых объяснений.

Comment: Может вам больше подойдёт sqlite?

Comment: Мне именно PostgreSQL нужен

Comment: А для каких целей вам нужен доступ до бд из приложения на unity?

Comment: Для того, чтобы сохранённые данные туда отсылать

Comment: Попробуйте поставить через unity nuget manager https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity